# PHP OOP, good practices in a class

Tags: php, oop

I am just getting started with PHP classes and my methods are all over the place.

Basically, as I need a new method I go to the bottom of the class and add it there.

Now finding what I need later on to make edits is quite a pain in the behind, is there any "good practices" for where to put public, private, static and accessor methods?

Comment: I always put method related to each other together.

Comment: While this is a good question it does not fit SO because there's not any absolutely correct answer and is very subjective. Personally, I always group class members (e.g. `attributes`, `getters`, `setters`, `helpers`, etc.) and mention this grouping in comment. So when I need to edit `getter`, I search for `getter` comment and start editing. I don't care how they are ordered, because almost any good IDE has outlining of your class, where you can easily find members.

Comment: Good question. Personally I have only ever thought of alphabetically ordered with getters and setters at the top so I'm interested in seeing some answers to this

Comment: Keep the number of properties in methods in a class low, and apply SOLID principles

Comment: Thanks guys! Mark, will look up SOLID principles... Rikesh, sometimes some methods are related to more than one other method... PLB, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't guidelines fixed in stone. It basically boils down to your own preference. The only thing you need to be sure is that you stay consistent within your own codebase.

Anyway, to answer your question, i'll give you my own personal style, from which you can take inspiration or derive your one.

In the first part, i define the attributes. First the class' constants, then static attributes, then public, protected and private attributes in this order.

In the second part I have the class' methods, which follow the same pattern as the attributes before: first the static ones, then public, protected, and private ones.

I usually put getters and setters (when available) on top of the other public methods.

Also, I usually give precedence to inherited / implemented methods from interfaces and parent class(es)

But again, this is just my own guideline.

Comment: Thanks for replying and for the tips. Am picking your answer as I will be using your tips/structure a little more than Bernhards. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In most codes, I see the following structure (top to bottom):

1. Fields (ordered by visibility)
2. Constructor and destructor
3. Methodes (again ordered by visibility, public first, than protected, than private)

But you can also refine this structure, e.g. put getters/setters at top or bottom of public methodes. Another way can be to order the private methodes after complexity (more magic methodes at the bottom), or you can order fields and methodes with same visibility alphabetical. Personally, I also prefer to put static variables first.

For sure, everyone will have his own style, and there will not be a "best" style, but generally it is good to have a structure, and not put anything anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Those are some great tips!